# problem using mock_model to test controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

I am trying to test a model but am having problems creating a mock model.

Here is part of the controller:

```
def show
    @license = License.find(params[:id])
```

Here is part of my rspec:

```
it "can show a license" do
   mocks = (1..3).map { mock_model(License) }
   License.should_receive(:all).and_return(mocks)       
   post :show, {:id => 1}
```

However, when i run my rspec i get an error:

```
Failure/Error: License.should_receive(:all).and_return(mocks)
(<License(id: integer, license_id: string, location: string, format: string, license_type: string, language: string, context: string, licensor: string, licensee: string, resource: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) (class)>).all(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

Also, if I got this to work, how can I change the id of one on the License objects.
would 'mocks[0].id = 5' work?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you performing the `License.all`?

Answer (score 0):

Should be `License.should_receive(:find).with(1).and_return(mock)` it this case only one mock will be enough: `mock = mock_model(License)`